# restore sql server 2008 database from .bak file using c#

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008

When I take backup and restore from that file using given code, it restore successfully but when I delete some rows of any table and restore my database from that same backup file, it give an error

> "Object reference not set to an instance of an object"

```
if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    cmd2 = new SqlCommand("USE MASTER RESTORE DATABASE plproject FROM DISK =   '" + openFileDialog1.FileName + "' WITH REPLACE", Con);
    dr = cmd1.ExecuteReader();
    //cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
    dr.Dispose();
    MessageBox.Show("Database Restored", "Information", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
}
```

Comment: You're creating `cmd2` - yet you're executing `cmd1` ??? Also: this is a query that doesn't return any data - so **don't use** `.ExecuteReader()` - use `.ExecuteNonQuery()` instead. Also: I would recommend to connect to the `master` database in the **connection string** and not use the `USE MASTER` inside your SQL statement

Answer (score 0):

Write a stored procedure or an SqlCommand as following. Check this [MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a928fa36-e285-476f-9a7b-6840a8bb7283)

```
USE master
GO
RESTORE DATABASE AdventureWorks2012
   FROM TAPE = '\\.\Tape0'
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

this cod  for me working .
send query by ado.net
("use master RESTORE DATABASE new_2SQL FROM  DISK = N'D:\backup.bak' WITH  FILE = 1,  NOUNLOAD,  REPLACE,  STATS = 10 ");